# Adaptar la camara completa a un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrolando un app para consulta de qr en una base de datos pero estoy teniendo problemas con la camara estoy usando la Libreria ZXING para capturar los datos del QR y generar la consulta

Pero al fragment solo se esta adaptando una parte de la camara, les comparto el XML y la clase de la camara para ver si me ayudan.

**Clase**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;



public class Camera extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    public static boolean mAutoFocus = false;
    public static int mCameraId = -1;

    class C03012 implements Runnable {
        C03012() {
        }

        public void run() {
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
        return mScannerView;

    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
        String sendTxt;
        sendTxt = rawResult.toString();

        Search search = new Search();
        search.setConsult(sendTxt);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).recibirTexto(sendTxt);
        mScannerView.postDelayed(new C03012(),20000000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            this.mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mAutoFocus = false;
                this.mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
                mScannerView.startCamera();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

 **XML**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.eslopezem.myapplication.Camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/camera_layout_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/camera_layout_margin_top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/scannner_view_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></fragment>
```

[image: App]